# Finding Customers Last Price Paid

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'm trying to find a way to get customers last price paid the code we have at the moment is:

```
SELECT Product.ProductCode,
       COUNT(Product.ProductCode) AS [Qty Baught],
       Product.Description,
       Customer.CustomerCode,
       Customer.Name,
       MAX(OrderHeader.DateTimeCreated) AS [Date],
       OrderLine.UnitSellPriceInCurrency AS Sell
FROM Customer
  INNER JOIN OrderHeader ON Customer.CustomerID = OrderHeader.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN OrderLine ON OrderHeader.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Product ON OrderLine.ProductID = Product.ProductID
GROUP BY Product.Description,
         Product.ProductCode,
         Customer.CustomerCode,
         Customer.Name,
         OrderLine.UnitSellPriceInCurrency
HAVING (Product.ProductCode = 'bcem002')
   AND (Customer.CustomerCode = '1000')
ORDER BY MAX(OrderHeader.DateTimeCreated) DESC
```

This code shows every time the price changed but I only want to see the last price, But the DateCreated and the price paid (UnitSellPriceInCurrency) are on different tables.

Is there a way to Group (UnitSellPriceInCurrency) by (DateCreated) or an alternative way of doing it.

I'm fairly new at this so if there's an obvious way of doing this sorry.

Edit:  What i'm getting at the moment with new code, Most of the prices i'm getting up are unrelated to the products

[image]

What I want is to get just the last price paid showing but in a way I can change the customer and the product that I'm searching for.

Comment: Please provide a http://www.sqlfiddle.com with the table structure and dumy data. Also show the expected output of it.

Comment: You can move your conditions to a WHERE clause instead. The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: Did you actually verify the important parts of the output to be valid? I keep seeing the `COUNT(Product.ProductCode) AS [Qty Baught]` - and doubt this bit to be correct...

Comment: @Abecee Yeah I know I've changed it to  "SUM(OrderLine.Quantity) AS [Qty Bought]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use a sub-select utilizing `TOP` to specify that you only want to retrieve one record, and make sure that it is the "latest" by using the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Product.ProductCode,
       COUNT(Product.ProductCode) AS [Qty Baught],
       Product.Description,
       Customer.CustomerCode,
       Customer.Name,
       MAX(OrderHeader.DateTimeCreated) AS [Date],
         (SELECT TOP 1 O.UnitSellPriceInCurrency 
          FROM OrderLine O 
          INNER JOIN OrderHeader OH ON O.OrderID = OH.OrderID 
          WHERE OH.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID AND O.ProductID = Product.ProductID
          ORDER BY OH.DateTimeCreated DESC) AS LatestPrice
FROM Customer
  INNER JOIN OrderHeader ON Customer.CustomerID = OrderHeader.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN OrderLine ON OrderHeader.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Product ON OrderLine.ProductID = Product.ProductID
WHERE  (Customer.CustomerCode = '1000') AND (Product.ProductCode = 'bcem002')
GROUP BY Product.Description,
         Product.ProductCode,
         Product.ProductID,
         Customer.CustomerCode,
         Customer.Name,
         Customer.CustomerID
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

In this example `LatestPrice` will contain the *last inserted UnitSellPriceInCurrency for each Customer and product*. I'm not sure if the query makes sense with your data (why get only the last price) but it's how I interpreted your request. The query will still return all OrderHeaders though.

Comment: Thanks but I get 
"Error in GROUP BY clause.
Unable to parse query text." Seems to do this when I take the Having off

Comment: thanks it did come up with an error saying OrderHeader.OrderID was not in the GroupBy so i put it in and now it just shows a list of all prices, Some of which look unrelated

Comment: @Richard I had another think of what it is you really want in terms of data. I changed the query to return the _latest price for each customer and product_. I feel it makes more sense, but you'll have to be the judge of that.

Comment: Sounds like what I want... I think, but i'm getting "Internal SQL Server error."

sorry to be wasting your time but the helps appreciated

Comment: No still get it the full error code is  
"Server: Msg 8624, Level 16, State 16, Line 1
Internal SQL Server error.
"   OrderLine has a PK of OrderLineID if thats anything to do with it.

Comment: @Richard Actually, it might be that your SQL can't handle the aliases of the sub-selects inner join. I moved them to a where-clause instead. Please try the query above again.

Comment: Yeah that worked!! is that because its an older SQL version?

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure to be honest. In some scenarios it seems to get confused when it comes to aliases and joins when you try to do things a bit too complex. Might be a version or service pack issue, but the end result is the same regardless (and it's actually more readable in the where-clause) :)

Comment: Thanks. this did exactly what I needed and it also allows me to leave product blank (Or select a product group) and it will show customers last price paid for all products which is great (But slowly on our system)

Comment: @Richard Yeh, this is not a friendly query for performance. It could be optimized quite a bit I think, but if it's worth it or not depends on the usage. For a busy front-end it would need to be improved. A way to possibly  get it faster would be to replace `ORDER BY OH.DateTimeCreated DESC` with `ORDER BY OH.OrderID DESC`, assuming it would give the same results (I figure the most recent Date would have the largest OrderID, but I can't know this). Reason being that OrderID should be indexed, and I guess the Date is not.

Comment: Just tried searching a product group with both methods. date took 34s and  by id took 18s and the results were the same so thanks again. Its not for front-end, it'll probably be ran once a year for each customer to compare last price paid with possible price increases. thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check of this works alright. It would be better if you posted a snapshot of the current result and the expected result you need.

```
            Select 
        *
        FROM
        (
        SELECT Product.ProductCode,
               COUNT(Product.ProductCode) AS [Qty Baught],
               Product.Description,
               Customer.CustomerCode,
               Customer.Name,
               OrderHeader.DateTimeCreated AS [Date],
               OrderLine.UnitSellPriceInCurrency AS Sell
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerCode,Customer.Name, OrderLine.UnitSellPriceInCurrency ORDER BY OrderHeader.DateTimeCreated) rnk
        FROM Customer
          INNER JOIN OrderHeader ON Customer.CustomerID = OrderHeader.CustomerID
          INNER JOIN OrderLine ON OrderHeader.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
          INNER JOIN Product ON OrderLine.ProductID = Product.ProductID
        WHERE Product.ProductCode = 'bcem002'
        AND   Customer.CustomerCode = '1000'
        GROUP BY Product.Description,
                 Product.ProductCode,
                 Customer.CustomerCode,
                 Customer.Name,
                 OrderLine.UnitSellPriceInCurrency
        ) tbl1 
        WHERE tbl1.rnk =1 
        ;
```